# Hinge animation not working. Seems a bake problem

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I´ve been meddling with this issue for weeks and still don´t know what the problem is. I want to make an animated object with a hinged part but the results are random: sometimes I get the hinge working when the object is static but not when I animate it and so on.

I suspect it´s something related to the baking, but I´ve tried to delete it, change the animation parameters to reset it, append in a new project... and nothing works.

Any suggestions?

I attach the project, in case you want to check it out.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9bbff0cd03b80a95dc507d8e55640edd20230405111629/3d845c5b16f140d4a946c0923594f2c420230405111650/c0d60c

Comment: Hello, so what animation are you trying to do and why are you using a rigid body instead of keyframes?

Comment: I want a character to throw the object, then it breaks when hits the ground. I want the hinged part to flap and bounce realistically when the object is carried by the character and later thrown. I thought that it would be faster and more reallistic if I made it with a simulation. Yes, at this point it would have been faster to keyframe it, but now I just want to learn what´s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just increase your speed of your pan like this:

[image]

then it works.

Physics is most about weights, speed, acceleration and how you have to combine them altogether so that it works ;)

[image]

you should give the upper part passive body too so that it looks more realistic...

[image]